# what is "request" in Django view

Tags: python, django

In the Django tutorial for the first app in Django we have

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")
```

And then the urls.py has

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from polls import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Now my question is what is the "request" parameter passed to the index function, also when the function index is called in urls.py it is not passed and variables it is just called as views.index in the line `url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),`

Comment: `views.index` in urls.py is not 'calling' the function, it is passing the function object itself as an arg to the `url` function... this allows Django to call the view function later, i.e. in response to a request for that particular url, at which point Django will call `views.index` passing a request object as the first arg

Comment: is 'request' a global value  it looks like it has to be otherwise how else would it be passed to HttpRespnse

Comment: No, it's not a global. And if it was a global it wouldn't need to be passed into the view function as an arg, you could just access it directly. see the 'scenic drive' video in laike9m's answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The request parameter is a `HttpRequest` object, which contains data about the request (see the [docs for django 3.2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/)).

In your urls file, you are not calling the `view.index` function, just listing a reference to it. Django then calls the function when a matching request comes in and passes the `HttpRequest` object as a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but I suggest you watch this video:

[A Scenic Drive through the Django Request-Response Cycle](http://pyvideo.org/video/2644/a-scenic-drive-through-the-django-request-respons)

This is a PyCon talk Dan Langer gave this year and showed how request and response work under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

From Django [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/request-response/). Request came from User that want to load page.

> When a page is requested, Django creates an HttpRequest object that
>   contains metadata about the request. Then Django loads the appropriate
>   view, passing the HttpRequest as the first argument to the view
>   function. Each view is responsible for returning an HttpResponse
>   object.