# In Django, how does passing in a reference to the views function eventually get called by the path function?

Tags: python, django

I know my question is very similar to [what is "request" in Django view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27169783/what-is-request-in-django-view) but I can't make sense of the answers provided. I have also read [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/views/) that is related to my question, but still don't understand. I would greatly appreciate any elaboration to the other answers in addition to anything I ask that isn't covered in that question.

In `views.py`, we can have something like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def home(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, World")
```

And in `urls.py` we have something like this:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='hello-world-home'),
]
```

My question involves `views.home` being passed in as a parameter to `path`. Based on one of the answers to a similar question, `views.home` is passing the "function object" as a parameter to `path`. If it's not calling the function, don't we need pass it like this: `views.home()`? How does it eventually get called by `path`?

If there is some documentation about being able to pass in a reference to a function in Python, I would appreciate it if you could link it.

Is being able to pass in a reference to a function exclusive to Python, or can it be replicated in a compiled language (i.e. C++)?

Comment: Everything in python is an object even functions are object.

Comment: I see, thank you. I was able to gather more information with what you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to understand it properly how the path function is working in Django you need to read the path method

Here is the link to go over Path definition.

https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/urls/conf.py#L57

Hope that will solve your confusion.

Comment: Thanks, this helps. Can you explain why `path` has an underscore before it so the function is `_path`? Wouldn't calling `_path` be different than calling `path`?

Comment: adding `_` into the path method make it private method in python. that's why underscore is added into the path method.

Comment: if it really help you please do accept the answer.

Comment: Accepted. Also, how did you find the method definition for `_path`? Did you use Github search?

Comment: Yes, you can go and change in django github repo